# Why scrollWidth doesn't work in this case in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm trying to make a simple marquee in Javascript, and need to **get the full content width of *innerDIV*** in the following:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="innerDiv" style="direction: rtl; white-space: nowrap; overflow: visible; position: relative;">
        very long ... text
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried **scrollWidth**. It works well in Chrome **but not in Firefox** (where it gives the value of clientWidth instead).

Here is a live demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/5fPGy/3/ (try it with Chrome and Firefox)

Does anyone know why? and how to get that full width?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I found an answer for your questions. This is a bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=833542.

Firefox returns for scrollWidth the clientWidth value. It should be fixed in Firefox 21.

For now, I used a workaround to get the correct scrollWidth on Firefox: set the overflow to hidden, get the correct scrollWidth and revert the overflow to visible. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/5fPGy/5/

```
var scrollWidth = $(ele).css("overflow", "hidden")[0].scrollWidth;
alert('clientWidt h = ' + ele.clientWidth + ',  scrollWidth = ' + scrollWidth  );
$(ele).css("overflow", "visible");
```

Best of luck,

Andrei

Comment: 2015 and this hack still seems to be needed -- at least on FF 36 on Windows. FF on Mac does not have the same problem.

Comment: 2020 and this still isn't fixed in Firefox

Comment: 2022 and still lacking a solution. Firefox is becoming the new IE.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
docWidth = Math.max(
        Math.max(frameDoc.body.scrollWidth, frameDoc.documentElement.scrollWidth),
        Math.max(frameDoc.body.offsetWidth, frameDoc.documentElement.offsetWidth)                               
);
```