# Inconsistent scrollwidth for iframe in FF/IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, iframe

I've got an iframe in my page, the contents of which are changed by clicking links in the main body of the page. I am trying to resize the width of the iframe to match the contents, like so:

```
frame.contentDocument.body.scrollWidth
```

This works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE, I get an iframe that shrinks each time a new link is clicked. FF seems to subtract 20-37px each click.

I have Googled and searched Stack Overflow. Some [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666931/why-scrollwidth-doesnt-work-in-this-case-in-firefox) I found were related to display and overflow CSS properties. I made the changes to the CSS, but it did not help. I also tried the FF 21 Beta in the hopes that it is fixed there, but it is not.

Comment: can you give an example jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided a jsFiddle, I can't tell you what you might be doing wrong, but I have had a go at trying to do what you are describing and I don't really experience any of the same issues which you are experiencing. It seems to work fine in all browsers you have mentioned. Provided that you ensure the document in the `iframe` is loaded by the time you are trying to get its `scrollWidth`, and you reset the width of the `iframe` to `0px` before you get the `scrollWidth`. This is to ensure that `scrollWidth` holds the width of the document, even when the previously loaded document was wider than the newly loaded document (in which case the `scrollWidth` would hold the `width` of the previous document inside the `iframe`).

Here's a <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VWnQh/16/)</kbd>. There is some randomization code in there for testing and demo purposes, The only bits that are important for you are:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("frame");

frame.onload = function () {
  $("#frame").css("width", '0px');
  $("#frame").css("width", frame.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollWidth + 'px');
}
```

I'm using some jQuery to make it easier for myself here, but you can probably replace that with whatever code you already have for setting the `width` of the `iframe`, and I'm using `frame.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollWidth` instead of `frame.contentDocument.body.scrollWidth`. This ensures that I'm getting the width of the `html` element instead of the `body` element, a part of your problem could be that the `html` or `body` tags on the document which is loaded into the `iframe` have `margins` or `paddings` set.

**Edit:**

I've had a bit more of a go and I *can* get the exact behaviour you are describing to happen both in Firefox and in Chrome. It happens if I don't set the `width` of the `iframe` to `0px` before reading the `scrollWidth`, the width of the currently loaded document is less than the width of the previously loaded document, and I have `overflow: visible` set on the `iframe`. Have a look <kbd>[here](http://jsfiddle.net/VWnQh/18/)</kbd> for an example of the behaviour. (It happens both in Chrome and in Firefox, as long as `scrolling` is set to `yes` and `overflow` is set to `visible`).

It seems that if I don't reset the `width` of the `iframe`, the `scrollWidth` holds the value of the `width` of the previously loaded document minus the width of the vertical scroll bar. So then, if I keep setting the `width` to the `scrollWidth`, every time I do so, and the newly loaded document is smaller than the previous document, the `width` of the `iframe` decreases by an amount of pixels equal to the `width` of the vertical scroll bar.

**Conclusion:** a definitive fix would be to set the `width` of the `iframe` to `0px` (**or anything less than or equal to the `minimum width` of the document which will be loaded**) before reading the `scrollWidth` of the `iframe`, which should happen after the new document is loaded.

Comment: I haven't actually had time to check the solution, but you put a lot of work in so I'll give you the bounty. I'll mark it as correct once I can confirm.

Comment: @CaptainThrowup - Have you confirmed yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `contentWindow` instead of `contentDocument`.