# Detect overflow fails in Firefox using (this.clientWidth < this.scrollWidth)

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, overflow

We're trying to detect if an element is overflowing using this simple Javascript code:

```
this.clientWidth < this.scrollWidth
```

This works perfectly on Chrome/IE but on Firefox it fails in until there's too much overflowing.

The example can be seen here: http://colnect.com/en/coins/countries#-1;yemen
This page show a list of countries. We do vertical centering of the text if it fits in a single line. If it's too long for one line (which is why we want to detect the overflow), we change it so the text appears in two lines.

In this attachment you can see what happens on Firefox (depending on the width of your window). When the overflow isn't "big enough", it's not detected even though CSS has clearly added the ellipsis for it so it IS overflowing. First 4 "countries" shown are correct (the 4th even broke into two lines) but the others are not.

To recreate, simply start resizing your Firefox window slowly until you see where this breaks.

Any ideas? A different way to detect overflow?

[image: Exampe]

Comment: So, this may be a silly question but, why do you need to do this? Why can't you just let the text break naturally? You can center it vertically without having to add a class to the container when it overflows.

Comment: You're welcome to suggest a way that would actually work well on that page as an answer here. It might not be as simple as you think.

Comment: It seems to work sometimes in Firefox, but not always... this may be a silly recommendation, but what if you changed it to this.clientWidth <= this.scrollWidth

Comment: @deebs When there's no overflow clientWidth == scrollWidth so your statement would always return true and thus not really detect overflow.

Comment: Please create a [small example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at http://jsfiddle.net , and add the example code to your question too.

Comment: Teemu, adding an example code would take some good time and might not re-create the conditions of this real-world question. I'm not trying to have a scholarly debated but rather find a workaround for what seems like a Firefox bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

**if you want to keep full name** then,  just remove `text-overflow:ellipsis;` from the selected class or id.

**if you want to  keep name in one line and no** `...` in last position, then  set `white-space: nowrap !important;overflow: hidden;` in selected class

**In my Firefox browser:**  (with center align and without `text-overflow:ellipsis;`)
[image]

(with center align and with `text-overflow:ellipsis;`)
[image]

**you can choice any one.**

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how this is an answer to the question. See the screen shot attached that shows what should be achieved. If the text fits in one line, it should be in the center. If it's longer, it can have two lines but the line-height goes back to 100% so the two lines are centered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Simply choosing `text-overflow:clip;` solves the problem here which is why I chose this answer. It doesn't, however, explain how to generally detect overflow in Firefox that would not be buggy but I guess it's one of these bugs that didn't affect enough people as of yet to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed two things with your website. You are using `white-space:nowrap` and you have a `transition: all` on the cell class. I changed those to `white-space:normal` and disabled the transition and it worked fine with the wrapping.
The reason i disabled the transition is that I found that sometimes it takes a moment to change the text and break it to two lines :)

Give it a try and let me know if that works.

Comment: When you change the `white-space:nowrap` the whole thing looks messy as the script never recognizes the need for 2 lines and thus some cells become double in height.

Answer (score 0):

...also keep in mind that having an ellipsis for overflown elements may force the ellipsis to appear because it might be larger in width than the last character. I have encountered some times where without ellipsis the whole text could be shown, while using ellipsis removed my last character.

Comment: Thank you for that notice but I don't see how it actually helps solve the issue at hand or answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [CodePen sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwyoEv).

```
<div id='mydiv'>Some relatively long line of text to test an interesting question about Firefox behavior.</div>
<br><br><br>
<div id='dbgmsg'></div>

#mydiv {
  width: 33%;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

$(document).ready(function insertAds() {

  function printWidthes(){
    var clientWidth = $('#mydiv').get(0).clientWidth;
    var scrollWidth = $('#mydiv').get(0).scrollWidth;
    $('#dbgmsg').html("clientWidth = " + clientWidth + "<br>scrollWidth = " + scrollWidth);
  }

  $(window).resize(function(){
    printWidthes();
  });

  printWidthes();
});
```

I've tested it on the latest Firefox version (35.0.1) on Window 7 and its behavior is absolutely correct. When the div size is less than the text size by even only one pixel then `clientWidth` becomes less than `scrollWidth`.

Try to test it on your computer; probably you have different Firefox version that causes the problem. BTW, did you saw that the numbers are wrong in debugger / print or it's just your guess? May be your site works wrong because any other reason?

Comment: Sorry but this isn't an answer to my question. Yes, I've tested the reasons for the bug I've described which of course wouldn't be clear in your example that doesn't show ellipsis. This doesn't seem to be specific to my FF version as it has been reported by various users of the website.

Answer (score 0):

*I think* this may be related to a (now resolved) bug in firefox.
Perhaps a different way of determining the scrollWidth and clientWidt is the answer (as brilliantly stated in [why scrollwidth doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666931/why-scrollwidth-doesnt-work-in-this-case-in-firefox)) :

Apparently by hiding the element before reading the `scrollWidth` gives a different value than when visible.

```
element=document.getElementById("my_div");
var scrollWidth = $(element).css("overflow", "hidden")[0].scrollWidth;
alert('clientWidt h = ' + element.clientWidth + ',  scrollWidth = ' + scrollWidth  );
$(element).css("overflow", "visible");
```