# need to adjust scroll left for the tabs to occupy in angularjs application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqlite

In my angularjs application I have approximately 23 tabs. So `90%` of the width I have given for tabs with `overflow : hidden`, and `10%` width `Prev` and `Next` icons. Each Tab has `36px` width. So by default on the page 5 tabs are getting visible. Now when I click `Next`,  I just want to scroll 5 tabs to left,  like this continue till the last tab visible. So in my `Next` icon click event I am trying to do this some thing like the following, in my controller, to get the max scroll left and then use it but in my code  `maxScrollLeft` is returning `NaN`.

```
 _self.getNextTabs = function () {            
          var maxScrollLeft = $element.scrollWidth - $element.clientWidth; 
          alert(maxScrollLeft);
          angular.element(document.querySelector('.main_tabSet .nav-tabs')).scrollLeft(600);    
        }
```

Here I have hard coded `.scrollLeft(600);` for testing purpose, so when I click `Next`, the tabs are scrolling left. But I want to make this scrolling to work correctly based on the max scroll left and the number of tabs that are being occupied. can any one help me in fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if _self.getNextTabs is in a directive, a controller or some other location, but the name $element indicates (to me) that it may be inside a directive?

If so, then I think $element may be a jquery object.  AND - if that's the case, then you would need to use the syntax `$element[0].scrollWidth` et al...

```
_self.getNextTabs = function () {            
   var maxScrollLeft = $element[0].scrollWidth - $element[0].clientWidth; 
   angular.element(document.querySelector('.main_tabSet .nav-tabs')).scrollLeft(600);    
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But now both scrollWidth and clientWidth are coming as 1353, do you know the reason, why both are same?

Comment: No idea as [this stack answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21064102/4747123) seems to indicate you are looking at the right properties... Unless using css overflow: hidden means scrollWidth=clientWidth.  [Maybe FFox issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15811768/4747123)

Comment: Actually it is inside controller, so I have given var maxScrollLeft  =  angular.element(document.querySelector('.main_tabSet .nav-tabs')).scrollWidth ; but maxScrollLeft  is coming as undefined.

Comment: These feel like different questions than your op. Angular.element() is just like $element. You need to add [0] before calling plain-old-js properties as angular.element() returns an array, not an element. Either close the question and ask another one or adjust as this is he right answer to the question you posed.

Comment: sure Bri, I have already accepted the answer. I post it as separated question.